# Android Studio: get ImageView and everything constrained on top of it

Tags: android

I would like to get image file containing not only ImageView, but also everything drew on top of it - for example I have textView constrained to be in the middle of ImageView, so I'd like to get sort of screenshot of it. Not whole screen - just the part of ImageView. Is this possible? My goal is then to send image via TCP or UDP to server.

I know I could maybe take screenshot of whole display and crop the image, but I would need to know exact coordinates of imageView to do so.

I expect to get an image file containing only cropped part of display, showing imageView part of screen.

Comment: I assume that ImageView is part of you appliaction, if so you would need to draw parent on bitmap and crop it to imageview bounds. Androidx core have extension [drawToBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).drawToBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) example: `Bitmap.createBitmap(parentView.drawToBitmap(), childView.left, childView.top, childView.width, childView.height)` - given that childView is direct child of parentView.

Comment: What would be equivalent for parentView and childView in MainActivity? "childView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);" does not work.

Comment: I have achieved almost full crop by using getLeft() instead of left and etc.

Comment: parentView and childView are your views from layout that you could get by findViewById or from binding

Comment: I have done this. It crops a bit too much from the top. But biggest problem, is that it crops the actual present view - if my imageView is not visible (need to scroll below), this wont work. Would it be possible to get non visible imageView?

Comment: as for cropping, it is probably due to margins on the view - you would need to get `childView.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams` and subtract top margin `childView.top - params.topMargin` and add top/bottom to height `childView.height + params.topMargin + params.bottomMargin`

Comment: as for non-visible image view - if it is inside recyclerview then it will be trickier and you would need to create layout without adding it to view hierarchy, call manually measure/layout on it and then try to draw to bitmap

Comment: I did add the status bar height, so now it crops well. And as now I simply made button for cropping imageView, under the same imageView, so it is always in screen.